# Qt- How to know about visibility of QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there anyway to check visibility of specific QDialog? I tried to check this. Here is my code:

```
MessageDialog::MessageDialog(QWidget *parent, int Id, QString Name, QPixmap *Photo)
: QDialog(parent),
  m_Id(Id),
  m_Name(Name)
{
    // ...

    if (MessageDialog.isVisible())
        qDebug()<<"visbile";
    else
        qDebug()<<"invisible";        
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> error: expected primary-expression before '.' token if (MessageDialog.isVisible())

Comment: `isVisible()` sounds good. What's not working?

Comment: `isVisible()` is correct but you can try out `MessageDialog.isActiveWindow()`. Check whether it works for you. This will tell that your dialog is active window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call a non-static function on your `MessageDialog` class. You should call the `isVisible()` function on your dialog object, in this case, you should use `this` or just call `isVisible()`.

```
if ( this->isVisible() ) // if ( isVisible() )
    qDebug()<<"visbile";
else
    qDebug()<<"invisible";
```

But I think it won't be good either, because in the constructor a dialog is not yet visible.

Comment: I want something to know when dialog was minimized. How to check it instead of using this conditional statement on constructor?

Comment: This property is only relevant for windows. I want something for Android and iOS too.

Comment: I didn't know that. In this case maybe you should reimplement the [hideEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hideEvent) function, but it's only an idea. And from that you can emit your own signal.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
MessageDialog.
```

i.e. leaving only

```
isVisible();
```